# How do Android control auto-wrapping for TextView?

Tags: android, textview

When text reach the end of the TextView, the next text will wrap to the new line.
How do Android implement/control this(So that we can override)?

I need to override something for my app, which doesn't do auto-wrapping correctly([known issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15597) on Android 3.0+) with ImageSpan. But I don't know where to start.

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470938/multiple-imagespan-in-honeycomb-break-the-edittext-textviews-auto-wrap) hoping to find a work-around for [the issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15597), but no answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend `TextView` and override the `paint()` method.